# Python pandas lower data AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to lower data taken from pandas sheet and trim all spaces then to look for an equality.

```
df['ColumnA'].loc[lambda x: x.lower().replace(" ", "") == var_name]
```

Code is above.
It says pandas series has no lower method. But I need to search for data inside column A via pandas framework while lowering all letters to small and whitespace trimmering.
Any other idea, how can I achieve in pandas?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but what does it mean "whitespace trimmering"? Remove leading and trailing whitespace or remove all whitespace?

Comment: yes) removing all spaces

Comment: yeah, your code helped. But I cannot accept till some time passes. Unfortunately now, I cannot have a index value of matched value and cannot understand if matching happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your lambda function, `x` is a Series not a string so you have to use `str` accessor:

```
df['ColumnA'].loc[lambda x: x.str.lower().replace(" ", "") == var_name]
```

Another way:

```
df.loc[df['ColumnA'].str.lower().str.replace(' ', '') == var_name, 'ColumnA']
```

Comment: second one gives a `series`